# User Based Login Page in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, url

Iam creating an angular app, in which the data will be displayed based on the user details entered in login page. 
In brief, I need help in acheiving the below:

1. When user enters username and Password, url will be built with these username and password and url will be called so that an unique id(a numeric digit) will be generated for each user. This unique id will be in a JSON format like {"Record":[{"Id":12}]}
2. Now if the unique id is returned from url, tab.html has to be displayed or if null is returned, an error message of wrong credentials has to be displayed.
3. For a successfully loggedin user, a table in tab.html will be displayed based on uniqueid which is generated from username and password.

Below is the code I have:

login.html:

```
<form ng-submit=submit()>
            <input type="text" name="username" placeholder="Username" ng-model="person.firstName" required />
            <span class="error" ng-show="mainForm.usernamename.$error.required">required</span>
            <input type="password" name="pswd" placeholder="Password" ng-model="person.pswd" required />
            <span class="error" ng-show="mainForm.pswd.$error.required">required</span>
            <div class="submit">
                <div>
                    <label>
                        <input name="remember" type="checkbox" data-ng-model="remember" data-ng-click="rememberMe()">   Remember Me
                    </label>
                </div>
                <input type="submit" value="LOGIN">
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-10"><p><a href="#">Forgot Password?</a></p></div>
            </div>             
        </form>
```

tab.html:

```
  <div ng-controller="SampleController">
        <table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover dataTables-example">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Name</th>
                    <th>ID</th>
                    <th>Qualification</th>         
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr ng-repeat="x in tableContent" >                 
                 <td>{{x.Name}} </td>
                    <td>{{x.DT}}</td>
                    <td>{{x.Qualification}}</td>
                  </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>      
</div>
```

app.js:

```
var wc = angular.module('wc', []);
wc.config(function ($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
$urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/login');
$stateProvider
         .state('login', {
             url: '/login',
             templateUrl: 'views/login.html',
             controller: 'LoginCtrl'
         })
.state('tab', {
    url: '/tab1',
    templateUrl: 'views/tab.html'
});
});

wc.controller('LoginCtrl', function ($scope,$http, $location) {
$scope.submit = function () {
     $http.get("URL-PartAame=" + $scope.person.firstName + "&Password=" + $scope.person.pswd)
       .success(function (data) {
//how to get the id from above url and display data based on condition//
           $scope.tableData = data;
           console.log(data)
           $location.path('/tab1');
       })
       .error(function (response, status, headers, config) { });
}
});
wc.controller('SampleController', function ($scope, $http, $modal) {
  $http.get("UrlA-UserId="returnedId)
    .success(function (response) {
        $scope.tableContent = response.Table;
    });
 };
```

I understood that this can be solved by using service or factory, but here how can a service be called along with the submit()? If this is not the correct way, please suggest the other way of doing it. Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `$state.go` and `$stateParams` service.

```
wc.controller('LoginCtrl', function ($scope,$http, $location, $state) {
$scope.submit = function () {
     $http.get("URL-PartAame=" + $scope.person.firstName + "&Password=" + $scope.person.pswd)
       .success(function (data) {
//how to get the id from above url and display data based on condition//
           $scope.tableData = data;
           console.log(data)

           $state.go('tab', {id: the_necesarry_id});
           //$location.path('/tab1');
       })
       .error(function (response, status, headers, config) { });
}
});


wc.controller('SampleController', function ($scope, $http, $modal, $stateParams) {
  var returnedId = $stateParams.id;
  $http.get("UrlA-UserId="returnedId)
    .success(function (response) {
        $scope.tableContent = response.Table;
    });
 };
```

Notice that you need add the `id` property contained in the $stateParams service in your url state.

```
.state('tab', {
    url: '/tab1/:id',
    templateUrl: 'views/tab.html'
});
```

Comment: Could you please let me know of how to get  `{id: the_necesarry_id}`? The actual JSON data returned from successful login will be like `{"Record":[{"Id":12}]}`

Comment: Getting this error: `Could not resolve 'tab1' from state 'login'`

Comment: oops failed to check a simple thing!! Thanx a lot for your helpful answer!!